# Vuetify 3 : Disable default styles

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I made a lot of component style in vuetify 2 / vuejs2 like this :

```
.custom_btn-contained {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: $color-primary !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  font: normal normal 600 13px/16px Montserrat !important;
  letter-spacing: 1.16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #041E4240;
  min-width: 64px;
  height: 34px !important;
}
```

It worked fine in Vue2 / Vuetify 2, but in Vue3 / Vuetify 3 some CSS are not applied, like the font-weight.
When I inspect the CSS I see this :

```
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

When I uncheck the font-weight it works fine, do you know how can I disable all vuetify styles or make my custom styles take priority ?

Comment: the CSS property needs to match exactly to be overridden.  `font` does not override `font-weight`.  make a custom `font-weight` property with `!important` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for you're answer but it doesn't work

Comment: That isn't from vuetify

Comment: Thanks a lot I found it by searching "box-sizing: border-box" on all my project